# Spring attached to a block

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy, spring

CONCEPTUAL DOUBT: Consider an ideal spring of length $l$, one end of which is fastened to a wall and the other attached to a block. Take the spring as the system. Now as the block is elongated by a distance $x$ slowly, the tension in the spring is $kx$, where $k$ is the spring constant. The work done on the spring by the external force (by the block) is $(1/2) kx^2.$ Now this should be the increase in the potential energy of the spring. But i am confused as to how do we know that the internal forces in the spring will be conservative. As the spring is massless so tension in the spring will be the same as kx but isnt it right that there will be no net force on a infintesmally small element of the spring as it's massless? So if there is not net force on an element(or no net internal force in the system which is taken as spring) then the rise in the potential energy of the spring is virtue of what? Because as far as i know there should be an internal conservative force for potential energy to be defined. Whats that force here?
Take the example of two identical particles with opposite charges(taken as a system) at rest. Both apply an attractive force on each other and therefore there is a net force on the constituent particles(charged particles here) unlike spring, which causes rise in kinetic energy of the individual particles which in turn results in the rise in kinetic energy of the system. And as both will move, the potential energy of the system changes as configuration changes.And as we know by coulomb's law that force between charged particles(internal force of the system) is conservative, therefore potential energy can be defined. But whats happening in the case of spring when its taken as a system,as the force which is conservative(kx) is an external force and there's no net internal force.
So can anyone tell whats wrong here?

Comment: If the spring is massless, Then you are not talking about a _physical_ spring. You are only talking about a hypothetical construct that strictly obeys Hooke's law. All real springs are made of "elements" that have mass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are internal forces. The $F=kx$ force is simply a linearization of a complicated summation of all the Coulomb electrical forces between the atoms of the spring.  The atoms are all being moved slightly further apart (on the whole) and experience an increase in electrical potential energy, which adds up over the whole length to $0.5kx^2$.

As far as taking an infinitesimal part of the stretched spring (continuum model, not atomic model), if you do this you will see an infinitesimal "cube" whose stress  state (Pascals or psi) has a net normal stress in the direction of the spring axis.  So there is in fact a normal force at the smallest level, but it's reported as a stress, not a force, because stress is independent of size.
You also stated that something massless cannot experience a force, but this seems like a misconception.

Comment: thanks for answering, but if we take spring and the block as the system after the spring has been elongated by x and then use energy conservation for the contraction of spring to contraction x as there is no external force. so when we write change in potential why dont we write final  as 0.5kx^2( the energy changed due to interaction of particles of spring, like when i took spring as the system)+0.5kx^2( due to the internal force kx acting between the "spring as a whole" and the block in action reaction pairs, as its internal as well as conservative)sorry 4 this dumb ques( i m in 9th grade)

Comment: how can a massless ideal spring experience a net force? according to F=Ma, it shouldnt experience net force if its mass is zero,right?

Comment: There are no dumb questions!  Your summation of the two 0.5kx^2 terms is correct, but they are of opposite sign.  So the total difference in energy between the stretched and retracted states is zero, as you might expect.

Comment: $F=ma$ means that the acceleration $a$ of a body is determined by the net force $F$ divided by the mass. With the spring you are talking about a static problem, so $F=0$ (no acceleration), but what this actually means is $F_1+F_2+F_3...=0$ for all the forces acting on the spring at a given time.  in your case there are only 2 forces, the externalforce pulling the spring, and the spring force resisting it. This equation tells us those two must be equal and opposite.

Comment: Another thing is, "massless springs" don't really exist, it's just that the mass has no bearing on the problem

Answer (score 0):

An ideal spring has no internal friction - not no internal force. The “internal force” you were curious about is the stress that builds within the spring’s material due to molecular-scale interactions taking place. As the spring is stretched, energy is stored within every piece of the it because it is being pulled in a direction that does not match the way that the metal has been moulded.

When you are thinking about energy transfers in the spring-block system, always come back to the law of conservation of energy when you’re stuck.

E (total) = E (spring) + E (block)

= (0.5 • k • 0^2) + (0.5 • m • v^2)

Imagine a situation where the block is stretched then released. As it moves back to equilibrium, x decreases so the amount of energy stored in the spring decreases. Since total energy remains constant, the kinetic energy of the block increases meaning that its speed increases as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: E (total) = E (spring) + E (block)

= (0.5 • k • x^2) + (0.5 • m • v^2)

Comment: ^^ slight edit, I realized there was a typo in the second line of the equation

Comment: thanks for answering ! i wanted to ask that how can a massless ideal spring experience a net force? according to F=Ma, it shouldnt experience net force if its mass is zero,right?

Comment: and how do we know that the internal stress is conservative so that it corresponds to potential energy?

Comment: First of all, there is no such thing as an ideal spring in real life. We only use it as an imaginary concept to make the math easier in situations where we can’t know how much energy is lost to internal friction.

Comment: Your statement about how a weightless object can’t experience a force is really an idea that relates more to an object’s motion through space. In theory, if an object had no mass it would always be moving incredibly quickly (like light). For the ideal spring, we don’t want it to be massless in this sense. We only call it massless so that we can make the assumption than no energy is lost as the spring bounce back and forth.

Comment: Last thing - spring force is an internal force (different from tension. Therefore, it is by definition a conservative force. I found a great site that explains this better than I’d be able to. Maybe you’ll find it useful too. https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/energy/Lesson-2/Internal-vs-External-Forces